# How can I be specific enough when targeting a link with css in a wordpress plugin?

Tags: css, wordpress

Recent Posts Widget Extended (RPWE) generates the post title as a link. On one particular page I'd like to disable the link around the title text. No class is generated by the widget for the link but there's a `rel`, which should be specific enough. I've added the following CSS:

```
a[rel="bookmark"] {
     pointer-events: none;
     cursor: default;
     text-decoration-line: none !important;
     font-size: 18px;
     color: #000000;
}
```

Everything worked except removing the underline. It looks like I'm not being specific enough?

Answer (score 0):

To remove underline you can use

```
text-decoration: none!important;
```

if still doesn't work for a element could be the text-decoration is applied at a child you could try:

```
a[rel="bookmark"] *{
   text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

If doesn't work means there is another rule with `!important` and you have to use the browser debugger tool.

Comment: Thanks... but text-decoration is shorthand for text-decoration-line, text-decoration-style & text-decoration-color. I've done the same code without being so specfic and using text-decoration. I've also tried a:link[rel="bookmark"] as a selector. Didn't work either!

Comment: I don't think `text-decoration-line` is supported from browser, http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-decoration

Comment: Have you tried to catch all children with * selector, as in my edited answer above?

Comment: Thanks. The a[rel="bookmark"] *{   text-decoration: none!important; } didn't work either. I'll have to have a look with debugger (I'm rusty with all of this, having not done any website stuff at all for the last few years). I hadn't realised that text-decoration-line only seems to work properly with Firefox (just Googled). I'll give the debugging a go and post back when I've succeeded!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using the  debugger tool, I discovered that a elements were inheriting
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 currentColor; I've now overidden this and my problem is solved! Thanks for steering me in the right direction with searching for a solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger tool in your browser to find why text-decoration:none; is being overridden. Usually there's a more specific selector being used. However in this case a wordpress style sheet was also using a border under all links:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 currentColor;
```

and this needed disabling too by selecting the link and styling with

```
box-shadow: none;
```